# Dynamic countdown timer in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-8

I want the implementation of the countdown in the online exam to be stored in the session. So when the user refreshes the browser the time is still running. What should I do in my laravel code? PLEASE Help me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var interval;
    var form = document.forms.exam;

    function countdown() {
        clearInterval(interval);

        interval = setInterval( function() {
            var timer = $('.js-timeout').html();
            timer = timer.split(':');
            var minutes = timer[0];
            var seconds = timer[1];
            seconds -= 1;
            if (minutes < 0) return;
            else if (seconds < 0 && minutes != 0) {
                minutes -= 1;
                seconds = 59;
            }
            else if (seconds < 10 && length.seconds != 2) seconds = '0' + seconds;

            $('.js-timeout').html(minutes + ':' + seconds);

            if (minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) { clearInterval(interval); form.submit(); alert("Waktu sudah habis!");}
        }, 1000);

        console.log(interval);
    }

    $('.js-timeout').html("{{ session('time') }}:00");
    countdown();
</script>
```